# When does my "too many rejected edits" expire?

Tags: support

I have been working on tags a *lot*, I mean, a *lot*, and a lot of them were approved. Some were also rejected though, and I suspect my hyper-tag-editing is the cause of my inability to review new answers and new user questions.  Does this inability expie with time?

Comment: It doesn't say "try again in *X* days" in that message?

Comment: it just says  "Too many of your edits were rejected."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It [seems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days) the full message used to read "Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days."  I'm not sure why it is cut off, but I would guess the ban still lasts 7 days.

Comment: This looks right, assuming he was automatically suspended and that this is the first time that happened to him.

Comment: Yes, it was my first time.